# How do I select an ID by its result set or get a better data model?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I'm having a little trouble with a selection and I was figuring I could either look for help in solving the selection or find a better way to model my data. My tables are structured such that:

```
Table A( a_id, a2, a3, a4)  pk: a_id
Table B( b_id, a_id, b3)    pk: b_id, a_id
```

Table B can have any number of entries for each b_id, but only one for each b_id, a_id. I want to be able to reference the set for each b_id to check for their existence so that the set is not duplicated. For example, say I had a tuple in table C

```
Table C( c_id, b_id )      pk:c_id
```

with a reference to a b_id of 1. If another tuple was to be inserted into C which results in the insertion of the same set represented by a b_id of 1 into table B, I would want the new tuple to have a b_id of 1, as well, instead of inserting into table B and using that b_id.

edit:

See [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c96d9/1). Say I wanted to insert a new object which is represented by the following inserts:

```
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 2, 11;
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 3, 5);
INSERT INTO C VALUES (2,3);
```

How can I query the database (or restructure) so that I can realize that the sets in Table B represented by a b_id of 1 or 3 would be the same? I would then want to change my logic so that the object being inserted is represented by the single statement:

```
INSERT INTO C VALUES (2,1);
```

A real-world-like example:

Imagine a player in a game. Each player in the game is a tuple in Table C. Each player can where any number of clothes - Table B. A piece of clothing is defined by the part of the body it covers (Table A) and its color (b3)
I want to find the player wearing a specific set of clothing. Lets say that player wore that same set again - I shouldnt have to add more data to table B, I should be able to say he wore it last game, so we'll just reference that set of clothing

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Can you illustrate the desired logic with some data sample?

Comment: Working on a sqlfiddle, thanks guys.

Comment: Added a sqlfiddle and more info about the situation

Comment: What if the new tuple is a subset of the existing one? What if the new tuple expands an existing one?

Comment: Then it should insert the sets into Table B that are representative of itself. I only want to search for the exact set.

Comment: a_id is unique for each b_id in Table B, so the primary key for B is the combination of b_id and a_id

Comment: OK, what's purpose of C? I m not quiet understand the problem yet. Maybe it is easier if you could provide a set of sameple data , as well as sample data what you are trying to get

Comment: C is just another Table used in the representation of the Object I am modeling. In a sentence I can say "An Object C has one set of Objects B which each are each represented by a unique object A and a TINYINT

Comment: If I wanted to insert an other object into C which had the same set of B as the first, I would not want to duplicate the set B and increase the size of the table when 75% of the time the set B might exist already.

Comment: From above I understand from you that: cid has many bid, bid has many aid. am i right?

Comment: cid has one bid, bid has many aid

Comment: OK thanks. now what is the question? what are you trying to get?

Comment: The set that is represented by bid using only the set of aid and b3

Comment: It must be that exact set, not a super or subset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101732/discussion-between-sidu-and-jlrosenberg).

Comment: This is correct except U is not in a table and is attempting to be inserted (only if needed) - which is why I would need a loop in a scripting language. Should I use a temporary table to achieve something like this or is there a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need programming language eg PHP to loop all the conditions:

```
SELECT B.b_id, BB.num, count(*)
FROM B, (
    SELECT b_id, count(*) num
    FROM B
    WHERE (a_id=1 and b3=1)
    OR    (a_id=2 and b3=11)
    OR    (a_id=3 and b3=5)
    OR    (a_id=4 and b3=6)
    -- you need programming language eg php to loop all your set data here
    GROUP BY 1
) as BB
WHERE B.b_id = BB.b_id 
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING count(*) = 4 and count(*) = BB.num
-- count(*) should be manually input to match above loop of OR
```

The sub-query get b_id and count, join back with B to match if they are exactly same.

Which means, you need to provide exactly same set of values [a_id, b3] to get correct value of b_id, not sub-set, not sup-set, exactly match.

In your example data, if you want to return bid=1, you need provide 3 sets of [aid,b3); if you want to return bid=2, you need to provide 4 sets of [aid,b3]

Comment: After much discussion, this is definitely the answer I am looking for. I will update my post with the real world example I gave you. The next step is to  create this functionality in a UDF...

Comment: After further inspecting, this answer is inadequate. By adding another OR
    OR    (a_id=4 and b3=6)
both b_id 1 and 2 are returned, when neither should be.

Comment: Are you sure? I have just run at your sqlfiddle, only bid=2 returned

Comment: My sqlfiddle test data is now different  than my own implementation since you used different values than I had originally entered. Change the insert statements into table B to match the set you are checking for in this answer.

Comment: The count(*) num is incorrectly returning a count of 4 for b_id 2 and since this so happens to match the number of items in the set represented by b_id 2, it is also being returned. This count should be 1.

Comment: You are right, I found the bug, you need to input exactly row count, instead of join. - try now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101735/discussion-between-jlrosenberg-and-sidu).

Answer (score 0):

If b_id, a_id do not constitute a unique identity for table B then you don't really have a pk.
Anyways, adding UNIQUE (a_id, b3) to your table B definition will prevent the duplicate entry values:

```
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 2, 8);
INSERT INTO B VALUES (3, 3, 10);
```

A foreign key constraint would then prevent:

```
INSERT INTO C VALUES (2,3);
```

But I don't think this approach is sufficient for what you are trying to do. For example would the insert into B above be ok if the existing records for B included another record, say 1, 5, 20?

Comment: b_id and a_id do represent a unique identity however. There is no foreign key constraint because I do not want the Object C to represent one Object B, but a set of them.

Comment: See the sqlfiddle above. Each tuple in Table B can be selected uniquely by b_id and a_id.

Comment: @jlrosenberg A foreign key is not a pointer. It is a statement that the values in one column are always in another column that allows the DBMS to exclude invalid states. Given a table holding rows where "object *c_id*  includes object *b_id*" and a table holding rows "object *c_id* has ..." then there is a foreign key {c_id} from the former to the latter.

Comment: My understanding of foreign keys might have been incorrect, as you pointed out, but foreign keys do not help me solve my problem.

Comment: @jlrosenberg Yes, as both you & @ Tumbleweed say. But it is a helpful addition to a solution.